# Get xml attribute using actionscript 2.0

Tags: xml, actionscript-2

I'm new at actionscript 2.0, and I'd like to know how to read a xml attribute's value while iterating the xml.

So far, I can get the xml elements, but I can't get this issue to work.

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, any element node has the property `attributes` ... this is simply an anonymous objects stuffed with the info ...

just do `someXML.attributes.someAttribute` and you will get the desired value ...

likewise, you may check out [this little library](http://code.google.com/p/as24x/) i made for AS2, to bring parts of [e4x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E4x) to the AS2 and simplify XML processing ... it is not at all production level though!

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 0):

Hum, need some code of yours to solve this mystery ;p  Otherwise you will get some boring links to the sdk documentation. But ill give it a shot, it's AS3 code and I don't know if xml had some major rework from AS2->AS3. Must say its a very nice experience to work with xml in AS3 though.

```
        //current level number
        public var mCurrentLevelNumber:Number = 0;
        //read from file variables:
        private var mLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        private var mXML:XML;

        //add a listener 
        mLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OnLoadXML, false, 0, true);
        mLoader.load(new URLRequest("../assets/content.xml"));

....
        /* 
        OnLoadXML
        Parses the data from the file, loads one level
        @e:Event    
        */  
        private function OnLoadXML(e:Event):void{   
            var loadLevel:Array = new Array();
            try{
                //convert the text into an XML
                mXML = new XML(e.target.data);
                //trace("reading from .xml is done, values: ", mXML);
                trace(" Name of the level: ", mXML.level[mCurrentLevelNumber].title.text() );
                for (var j:int=0; j<mXML.level[mCurrentLevelNumber].tiles.tilerow.length(); j++) {
                        trace("Row",j,", tiles:", mXML.level[mCurrentLevelNumber].tiles.tilerow[j].text() );
                }
                //......
                //}  
            }catch (e:TypeError){
                trace("Could not parse the XML");
                trace(e.message);
            }
        }


And the xml file structure;
<!-- pretty level arrays... -->
<levels>
    <level>
        <title>Level 1</title>
        <tiles>
            <tilerow>1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 1 1 1 3 1 13</tilerow>
            <tilerow>1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 12 0 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1</tilerow>
            <tilerow>1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 11 11 11 12 0 6 1 0 0 0 0 1</tilerow>
            <tilerow>1 9 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 12 0 9 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 1</tilerow>
        </tiles>
    </level>
</levels>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I'll post below how I'm getting the xml elements' values. What I don't know is how to get the attributes of each element. For example:

<Levels><Level id="1">Stage 1</Level></Levels>

I already know how to get "Stage 1" but also I'd like to get the value for the id attribute.

So well, I'm getting each xml item like this(inside a for):

var myXml:XML = new XML();
var bars:Array = new Array();
if(myXml.childNodes[0].childNodes[chartIndex].nodeName=="level")
{
bars.push[myXml.childNodes[0].childNodes[chartIndex].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue]
}

Thanks,

Brian